# How to check how many letters are in a string in java?

Tags: java, string

How do you check how many letters are in a Java string?

How do you check what letter is in a certain position in the string (i.e, the second letter of the string)?

Comment: Is this homework? Have you tried looking at the Javadocs for the `String` class?

Comment: Did you read the Java API doc for `String`? It details the methods that tell you its length, as well as checking the character at a position. [link for the google challenged](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: No, this isn't for homework, just a program I'm working on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count letters in a string Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163876/count-letters-in-a-string-java)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

A)

```
String str = "a string";
int length = str.length( ); // length == 8
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29

**edit**

If you want to count the number of a specific type of characters in a `String`, then a simple method is to iterate through the `String` checking each index against your test case.

```
int charCount = 0;
char temp;

for( int i = 0; i < str.length( ); i++ )
{
    temp = str.charAt( i );

    if( temp.TestCase )
        charCount++;
}
```

where `TestCase` can be `isLetter( )`, `isDigit( )`, etc.

Or if you just want to count everything but spaces, then do a check in the `if` like `temp != ' '`

B)

```
String str = "a string";
char atPos0 = str.charAt( 0 ); // atPos0 == 'a'
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29

Comment: I think the number of letters is not necessarily equal to the string length - whitespace is not considered a letter, or is it?

Comment: I assumed he meant a simple string length. I'll edit with what your case

Comment: Sure, just wanted to make the question a bit more interesting ;) +1 anyway

Comment: Ok, new problem: my code editor, NetBeans, dosen't know the length() method. What should I do?

Comment: @tussya That is very odd... How are you using it?

Comment: int cleartextl=textaclr.length();   and                           for(int i=0;i>textaclr.length();i++){

Comment: @tussya is `textaclr` a `String` object? There should be no reason why that does not work if it is.

Comment: Yeeeah, that was the problem.

Comment: If you are counting letters, the above solution will only work with ASCII characters.  For example

Comment: Does the space between the parenthesis in the above answer mean something? Or is `str.length( )` the same as `str.length()` ?

Answer (score 7):

If you are counting letters, the above solution will fail for some unicode symbols.  For example for these 5 characters sample.length() will return 6 instead of 5:

```
String sample = "\u760c\u0444\u03b3\u03b5\ud800\udf45"; // 瘌фγε
```

The codePointCount function was introduced in Java 1.5 and I understand gives better results for glyphs etc

```
sample.codePointCount(0, sample.length()) // returns 5
```

http://globalizer.wordpress.com/2007/01/16/utf-8-and-string-length-limitations/

Answer (score 5):

To answer your questions in a easy way:

```
    a) String.length();
    b) String.charAt(/* String index */);
```

Comment: String.length() returns the number of Unicode units, not the number of characters. The result will be correct only if every letter in a string is exactly 1 Unicode unit.

Answer (score 0):

1) To answer your question:

```
  String s="Java";
  System.out.println(s.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get any of these answers to work for me using `UTF-8`. If you are using `UTF-8`, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511490/calculating-length-in-utf-8-of-java-string-without-actually-encoding-it) post. I ended up using [`Guava's Utf8`](https://github.com/google/guava).