# Calculating length in UTF-8 of Java String without actually encoding it

Tags: java, utf-8

Does anyone know if the standard Java library (any version) provides a means of calculating the length of the binary encoding of a string (specifically UTF-8 in this case) without actually generating the encoded output? In other words, I'm looking for an efficient equivalent of this:

```
"some really long string".getBytes("UTF-8").length
```

I need to calculate a length prefix for potentially long serialized messages.

Comment: If your problem is raw speed, and not memory, are you sure that an ad-hoc function would be faster than `getBytes` + `length`? The current JREs have quite fast conversion routines implemented in native code.

Comment: I'm concerned about memory pressure too, but the main concern is that large allocations could cause more garbage collection overhead. Rather than introducing a potential performance issue (that needs to be verified by profiling, of course), I thought I'd ask if there was a more specific API available. BTW, Oracle's JRE does not use native code for this: they allocate a worst-case byte array (`maxBytesPerChar`) and use an array-based implementation of CharsetEncoder (see `sun.nio.cs.UTF_8`).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here's an implementation based on the [UTF-8 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629#section-3):

```
public class Utf8LenCounter {
  public static int length(CharSequence sequence) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0, len = sequence.length(); i < len; i++) {
      char ch = sequence.charAt(i);
      if (ch <= 0x7F) {
        count++;
      } else if (ch <= 0x7FF) {
        count += 2;
      } else if (Character.isHighSurrogate(ch)) {
        count += 4;
        ++i;
      } else {
        count += 3;
      }
    }
    return count;
  }
}
```

This implementation is not tolerant of malformed strings.

Here's a JUnit 4 test for verification:

```
public class LenCounterTest {
  @Test public void testUtf8Len() {
    Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    AllCodepointsIterator iterator = new AllCodepointsIterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      String test = new String(Character.toChars(iterator.next()));
      Assert.assertEquals(test.getBytes(utf8).length,
                          Utf8LenCounter.length(test));
    }
  }

  private static class AllCodepointsIterator {
    private static final int MAX = 0x10FFFF; //see http://unicode.org/glossary/
    private static final int SURROGATE_FIRST = 0xD800;
    private static final int SURROGATE_LAST = 0xDFFF;
    private int codepoint = 0;
    public boolean hasNext() { return codepoint < MAX; }
    public int next() {
      int ret = codepoint;
      codepoint = next(codepoint);
      return ret;
    }
    private int next(int codepoint) {
      while (codepoint++ < MAX) {
        if (codepoint == SURROGATE_FIRST) { codepoint = SURROGATE_LAST + 1; }
        if (!Character.isDefined(codepoint)) { continue; }
        return codepoint;
      }
      return MAX;
    }
  }
}
```

Please excuse the compact formatting.

Comment: That should work, but it's needlessly complicated: you don't need to support 5- and 6-byte characters (since Unicode doesn't allow, and UTF-16 can't represent, codepoints that high), and if `Character.isHighSurrogate(ch)`, then you don't actually need to determine the codepoint: the set of codepoints that require surrogate pairs in UTF-16 is the same as the set of codepoints that require four bytes in UTF-8. Therefore, if it's O.K. not to support invalid surrogate pairs, then you can just write

Comment: `if(ch <= '\x7F') ++count; else if(ch <= '\u07FF') count += 2; else if(Character.isHighSurrogate(ch)) { count += 4; ++i; } else count += 3;`. But +1 for including a super-comprehensive unit-test. :-)

Comment: @ruakh - all good points; I've updated the answer with your implementation.

Comment: @McDowell, I think there's an error in your unit test code. The current code excludes MAX, but MAX is a valid codepoint, isn't it?

Comment: The test case could be even more compact when using a simple `for` loop instead of that `AllCodepointsIterator`. Further, there are already convenient constants in `java.lang.Character`: `for(int codepoint=Character.MIN_CODE_POINT; codepoint<=Character.MAX_CODE_POINT; codepoint++) {  if(codepoint == Character.MIN_SURROGATE) codepoint=Character.MAX_SURROGATE+1;
 if(!Character.isDefined(codepoint)) continue;
 String test = new String(Character.toChars(codepoint));
 Assert.assertEquals(test.getBytes(utf8).length, Utf8LenCounter.length(test)); }`

Answer (score 27):

Using Guava's [Utf8](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Utf8.html#encodedLength(java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
Utf8.encodedLength("some really long string")
```

Comment: Added in Guava 16.0, released in early 2014.

Answer (score 2):

The best method I could come up with is to use CharsetEncoder to write repeatedly into the same temporary buffer:

```
public int getEncodedLength(CharBuffer src, CharsetEncoder encoder)
    throws CharacterCodingException
{
    // CharsetEncoder.flush fails if encode is not called with >0 chars
    if (!src.hasRemaining())
        return 0;

    // encode into a byte buffer that is repeatedly overwritten
    final ByteBuffer outputBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

    // encoding loop
    int bytes = 0;
    CoderResult status;
    do
    {
        status = encoder.encode(src, outputBuffer, true);
        if (status.isError())
            status.throwException();
        bytes += outputBuffer.position();

        outputBuffer.clear();
    }
    while (status.isOverflow());

    // flush any remaining buffered state
    status = encoder.flush(outputBuffer);
    if (status.isError() || status.isOverflow())
        status.throwException();
    bytes += outputBuffer.position();

    return bytes;
}

public int getUtf8Length(String str) throws CharacterCodingException
{
    return getEncodedLength(CharBuffer.wrap(str),
        Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder());
}
```

Comment: This is a perfectly good way to do it. Yes, you do encode the characters, but that isn't that much more time consuming as calculating the size of each character. And the best thing of course is that it will always return the correct result. A buffer of 1024 bytes hasn't hurt anybody either.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop thru the String:

```
/**
 * Deprecated: doesn't support surrogate characters.
 */
@Deprecated
public int countUTF8Length(String str)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
    {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c < 0x80)
        {
            count++;
        } else if (c < 0x800)
        {
            count +=2;
        } else
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented yet");
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Close, but not quite: you're not handling surrogate characters properly. In particular, `c < 0x10000` (which is what you meant when you wrote `c < 0x1000`) is guaranteed to be true, because code-points outside the BMP are expressed as *two* Java characters (using surrogate code-points).

Comment: @ruakh: Ah, yes I see. Indeed. That is correct. I thought to make a quick solution, but the surrogate characters are indeed a problem to be completely correct... But if it is outside the OP his needs, this will satisfy.

Comment: This would return 8 for a surrogate pair, which wouldn't be correct. For such subtle reasons, I'm trying to avoid writing this code myself.

Comment: Is there even a guarantee on back and forth between 8-16 on combining characters vs precomposed characters? (That the encoder implementation observes?)  I would be dubious of trusting something not generated by the encoder that will crank out the final output.

Comment: @Affe: I don't know of such a guarantee, but I find it *really* hard to believe that anyone would write an encoder that implicitly (and silently) modified the character sequence. I mean, that would mean that encoding and then decoding the sequence would result in a new string that isn't `equals`-equivalent to the old one!