# Decode a single character from octets in lisp

Tags: string, unicode, lisp, common-lisp

How can I decode a single character from a vector of octets in common lisp?

I want something like:

```
(decode-character vector :start i :encoding :utf-8)
```

or more specifically:

```
(decode-character #(195 164 195 173 99 195 176) :start 0)
=> #\LATIN_SMALL_LETTER_A_WITH_DIAERESIS
```

which would return the UTF-8 encoded character that starts at position `i` in `vector`.

I can't figure out how to do that using either babel or flexi-streams.

Comment: You can have a look at [trivial-utf-8](https://common-lisp.net/project/trivial-utf-8/)

Comment: @coredump trivial-utf-8 doesn't have what I'm looking for, and only supports utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 3):

```
(defun decode-character (vector &rest args)
  (char (apply #'babel:octets-to-string
               (coerce vector '(vector (unsigned-byte 8))) args)
        0))
```

Comment: I would not `coerce` but `check-type` before.

Comment: The `encoding` keyword parameter seems relevant for the question.

Comment: This would work if it used the start and end keyword arguments as in @coredump's answer. I was hoping for something that didn't unnecessarily create a string, but this works at least.

Comment: @Thayne If you need to work at a lower level, you can also look how octets-to-string is implemented. Maybe introducing a custom `read-character` function that gets the next character from a stream is not too hard to implement.

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe not what you are looking for (I'd gladly update if I can).
I did not look at Babel, but you could generalize the approach for other encodings I guess. I'll stick with `trivial-utf-8` here. I would do this:

```
(defun decode-utf-8-char (octet-vector &key (start 0))
  (char (trivial-utf-8:utf-8-bytes-to-string 
          octet-vector
          :start start
          :end (+ start 4)) 0))
```

Gives the result you want with your example vector.
The reason it works is because utf-8 characters are at most [4 bytes long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533258/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-bytes-for-a-utf-8-encoded-character). The call to `char` is here to grab the first character in case more than one were actually read.