# Get a `Char` from a `ByteString`

Tags: haskell, text, utf-8, ghc, bytestring

Is there a way to get the first UTF-8 `Char` in a `ByteString` in O(1) time? I'm looking for something like

```
headUtf8 :: ByteString -> Char
tailUtf8 :: ByteString -> ByteString
```

I'm not yet constrained to use strict or lazy `ByteString`, but I'd prefer strict. For lazy `ByteString`, I can cobble something together via `Text`, but I'm not sure how efficient (especially space-complexity wise) this is.

```
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as T
import Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding (decodeUtf8With, encodeUtf8)
import Data.Text.Encoding.Error (lenientDecode)

headUtf8 :: ByteString -> Char
headUtf8 = T.head . decodeUtf8With lenientDecode

tailUtf8 :: ByteString -> ByteString
tailUtf8 = encodeUtf8 . T.tail . decodeUtf8With lenientDecode
```

In case anyone is interested, this problem arises when using Alex to make a lexer that supports UTF-8 characters<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> I am aware that since Alex 3.0 you only need to provide `alexGetByte` (and that is great!) but I still need to be able to get characters in other code in the lexer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the [Data.Bytestring.UTF8](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/utf8-string-1.0.1.1/docs/Data-ByteString-UTF8.html) module in the utf8-string package.  It contains an `uncons` function with the following signature:

```
uncons :: ByteString -> Maybe (Char, ByteString)
```

You can then define:

```
headUtf8 :: ByteString -> Char
headUtf8 = fst . fromJust . uncons

tailUtf8 :: ByteString -> ByteString
tailUtf8 = snd . fromJust . uncons
```

Comment: I did not know this package existed, but this is exactly what I was looking for. This means I can completely eliminate any dependency on `text`.

Comment: Wow! This tiny library has precisely the functionality I need for my lexer. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Just keep in mind these functions are partial; they are undefined on `Data.ByteString.empty`.

Answer (score 0):

[The longest UTF-8 encoding is 6 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35027139/477476), so if we try 1, 2, ... bytes, it will finish at least at the 6th step, thereby being *O(1)*:

```
import Data.Text as Text
import Data.Text.Encoding as Text
import Data.ByteString as BS

splitUtf8 :: ByteString -> (Char, ByteString)
splitUtf8 bs = go 1
  where
    go n | BS.null slack = (Text.head t, bs')
         | otherwise = go (n + 1)
      where
        (bs1, bs') = BS.splitAt n bs
        Some t slack _ = Text.streamDecodeUtf8 bs1
```

For example, here's splitting a 2+3-byte `ByteString`:

```
*SO_40414452> splitUtf8 $ BS.pack[197, 145, 226, 138, 162]
('\337',"\226\138\162")
```

and here a 3+2-byte one:

```
*SO_40414452> splitUtf8 $ BS.pack[226, 138, 162, 197, 145]
('\8866',"\197\145")
```

Comment: The longest UTF-8 encoding is 4 bytes.  5 and 6 byte encodings are invalid and have been invalid for many years.  No characters were ever assigned which would have had 5 or 6 byte encodings.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: thanks. My argument only needs the longest UTF-8 encoding to be a finite number :)