# Get length of encoded message in bytes without creating the object C#

Tags: c#

I would like to get the number of bytes in a string using UTF-8 encoding without explicitly creating an array of bytes (because I do not need to use the array, just the number of bytes). Is this possible? My question is almost exactly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852460/get-size-of-string-w-encoding-in-bytes-without-converting-to-byte) but with C# instead of Java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the method [GetByteCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytecount?view=net-7.0) to get the number of bytes that the string would produce with a given encoding.

```
var byteCount = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount("myString");
```