# Count letters in a string Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm doing an assignment where I'll have to code a program to read in a string from user and print out the letters in the string with number of occurrences. *E.g. "Hello world" in which it should print out "h=1 e=1 l=3 o=2 ... etc.", but mine only write "hello world" and the amount of letters in total.* I can't use the hashmap function, only arrays. Can someone give me a hint or two on how to proceed from the written code below to get my preferred function? I don't understand exactly how to save the written input in array.

Here's my code so far.

```
public class CountLetters {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write a sentence." );
        int amount = 0;
        String output = "Amount of letters:\n";

        for ( int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++ ) {
            char letter = input.charAt(i);
            amount++;
            output = input;
        }
        output += "\n" + amount;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, output,
                             "Letters", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and remove everything that is not related to your question. Swing doesn't matter.

Comment: Create an array with 26 elements. Increment the one that corresponds to a letter - by noticing that the ASCII values of letters are sequential (subtract a constant from the ASCII value to get the index of the element you need to increment). Be careful of values outside of the range `A-Z`, and make sure you deal with the lower case / upper case issue. Print the result for only non-zero elements. Good luck with your homework.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need 26 `switch` cases. Just use simple code to count letter:

```
    String input = userInput.toLowerCase();// Make your input toLowerCase.
    int[] alphabetArray = new int[26];
    for ( int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++ ) {
         char ch=  input.charAt(i);
         int value = (int) ch;
         if (value >= 97 && value <= 122){
         alphabetArray[ch-'a']++;
        }
    }
```

After done count operation, than show your result as:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < alphabetArray.length; i++) {
      if(alphabetArray[i]>0){
        char ch = (char) (i+97);
        System.out.println(ch +"  : "+alphabetArray[i]);   //Show the result.
      }         
 }
```

Comment: Actually - one more comment. `isLetter` does not guarantee that `letter - 'a'` is in the range `[0, 25]`. "Other" characters (accented, etc) will cause your code to crash.

Comment: Might I suggest one last improvement: `int chIndex = (int) ch - 'a'; if (chIndex >= 0 && chIndex < 26) alphabetArray[chIndex]++;` is a touch more readable (although it is functionally equivalent).

Answer (score 2):

- Create an integer array of length 26.
- Iterate each character of the string, incrementing the value stored in the array associated with each character.
- The index in the array for each character is calculated by `x - 'a'` for lower case characters and `x - 'A'` for upper case characters, where `x` is the particular character.

Comment: When I started typing this answer there were no answers and only the comment by Technodrama. I guess I am just a slow typist.

Comment: Don't worry - I just thought it was funny. It is my preference, when people post "help me with my homework" questions, to only write comments with hints - let them do a bit more of the thinking.

Comment: Hello Floris. OP here. That's my preference too, hints. Which is why I asked in my post "drop a hint or two" giving that this is homework. I managed to code a somewhat OK program from your post, Colin, but Masud's post helped me optimize it further to perfect state in which I learned a trick or two. I wish I could give you a vote up, but it says I need 15 posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Array which first element will represent 'a', second 'b', etc. If you need distinction between lower and upper cases than you can add it at the end. This array will have all values equals 0 at the beginning.
Then you iterate through your sentence and you increment required values on the array.
At the end you print all values that are > 0. Simple?

Let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

No you should not create an array of 26. This will break if the string contains unexpected characters. (ä, ö, ü anyone?)
As I pointed out im my comment use a Map. This will work forr all posible characters out there.

Comment: Well as much as we love Map, the OP is not allowed to use that. OP clearly states that *I can't use the hashmap, only arrays*. Why would you still suggest a map based solution?

Comment: Convert to lower case, subtract `'a'`, check that you are between `0` and `25`, then increment. Otherwise do nothing.

Comment: Also if you still want to handle the cases for special characters why not create an array size of all unicode characters(95,221) and repeat the same procedure. It is inefficient to hold space for over 95K memory locations in memory but handles the special characters effecively

Answer (score 0):

import java.io.*;

public class CharCount {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    int i,j=0,repeat=0;
    String output="",input;
    char c=' ';
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("enter name ");
    input=br.readLine();
    System.out.println("entered String ->\""+input+"\"");
    input=input.toLowerCase();

    for(i=0;i<input.length();i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<output.length();j++)
        {
            if(input.charAt(i)==output.charAt(j) || input.charAt(i)==c)
            {
                repeat=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(repeat!=1)
        {
            output=output+input.charAt(i);
        }
        repeat=0;
    }

    System.out.println("non-reepeated chars in name ->\""+output+"\"");

    int count[]=new int[output.length()];
    for(i=0;i<output.length();i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<input.length();j++)
        {
            if(output.charAt(i)==input.charAt(j))
                count[i]=count[i]+1;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<output.length();i++)
        System.out.println(output.charAt(i)+"- "+count[i]);
}
```

}