# Count letters in a string

Tags: java, count

I need to find an algorithm which counts the letters in any string (e.g. "cabababb") and the output must be in a alphabetical manner(e.g. a: 3, b: 4, c:1 etc.) . There is no need to distinguish between upper and lower case letters. I am not allowed to youse a HashMap.

This is my code till now: I'ts not working, I think I've got the wrong strategy here. Can you help me please?

```
public class Stringray extends MiniJava{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Texteingabe
    String input = readString("Geben Sie einen Text ein: ");

    String output = "";
    int i = 0;

    // Häufigkeit der Buchstaben
    int count = 0;
    char letter = 'a';
    while(i < input.length()) {
            while(i < input.length()) {
                if(input.charAt(i) == letter) {
                    while(i < input.length()) {
                        count++;
                        i++;
                    }
                    output = output + letter + ": " + count + "\t";
                }
                i++;
            }
            letter++;
    }
    write(output);
}
}
```

Comment: Your code is not working because you are using first of all the same index for all 3 loops. Also since you want the output sorted, why don't you just sort and run a linear scan of the characters printing as you are about to change to a "higher" char?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count letters in a string Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163876/count-letters-in-a-string-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem by following the steps below like QBrute correctly pointed out.

```
public String countMatches(String main) {
    //Create an array of the alphabets length
    main = main.toLowerCase();
    int[] foundArray = new int[26];
    String output = "";
    //Create an alphabets array
    String[] alphabets = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z".split("\\s");
    //Split the main String array
    String[] mainArray = main.split("");
    for (String string : mainArray) {
        //Iterate through the array
        for (int i = 0; i < alphabets.length; i++) {
            //If the string index matches any of our alphabets
            if (string.equals(alphabets[i])) {
                //Increase the corresponding foundArray index value
                foundArray[i] = foundArray[i] + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    //Iterate through the foundArray
    for (int i = 0; i < foundArray.length; i++) {
        //If an index is greater than 0
        if (foundArray[i] > 0) {
            //A match was found
            //Assign the matched foundArray index to the corresponding alphabet
            output += alphabets[i] + ":" + foundArray[i] + ", ";
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This looks actually very good. But I am not quite sure if I understand the "String[] alphabets = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z".split("\\s");
    for (String string : main.split("")) {" What exactly is happening in this argument?

Comment: You can also create an alphabet array manually like this : String[] alphabets = {"a","b","c", "d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"}; or using a manual char array but it's slower than just splitting it.

Comment: I got it. But there is an exception at this point (main.split("")), it sais "main cannot be resolved"; Do you know what is meant by this?

Comment: It is still a mistake there, but do I need the for loop with main.split when I am using the long version of the string alphabet array?

Comment: Yes you still need the loop. But the problem isn't coming from there. Did you change the function parameter variable? I mean the "public String countMatches(String main) {" the "String main" part of the code? If yes, then you'll have to replace "main" with the variable you change it with.

Comment: Thanks got it. But where can be a string entered and converted into an array in your code?

Comment: Just call the function the way you call other ones. e.g String matches = countMatches(yourdata); Don't forget to accept the answer once you're done.

Comment: But can I use the String input = readString("Geben Sie einen Text ein: "); in the main method without to use a new method?

Comment: Yes you can if you renamed the countMatches method to "readString".

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple algorithm:

1. Create an empty `int[]` array of length `26`, it will be initialized with `0`s
2. Iterate your String
3. Get the `char` at the current index.
4. Tricky part: You need a mapping between a given `char` and its corresponding index (e.g. `a` would be index `0`, `b` would be index `1` and so on). Have a look at an ASCII-Table for this
5. Add 1 to the element at the mapped index of the created array.
6. At the end, iterate the array and only print the values that are not `0` along with the corresponding `char` at that index (Need the ASCII mapping again here)

Answer (score 1):

A really preformant way to do this in linear time is using a HashMap

```
public class Stringray extends MiniJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Geben Sie einen Text ein: ";
        System.out.println(countLetters(input));
    }

    public static HashMap<Character, Integer> countLetters(String input) {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        final int length = input.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            Character currentChar = Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i));
            if (Character.isAlphabetic(currentChar)) {
                if (hashMap.containsKey(currentChar)) {
                    hashMap.put(currentChar, hashMap.get(currentChar) + 1);
                } else {
                    hashMap.put(currentChar, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        return hashMap;
    }

}
```

You need to consider that Upper and Lower case are the same and discard non alphabetic characters. Once you have all the information in the hashmap, the way you show it console is another matter. If you need to show a zero for the letters that are not present in your text it would be better to initialize the hashmap to that.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I am not allowed to use a hashMap.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure whether this is a trick question. But really all you have to do it seems is to create a method that counts the number of occurrences of a character in String. The code below how to do this is the easiest way possible. I leave it to you to modify it such that it fits all your testcases.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String input = "cabababb";
    char[] testCharacters = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
    for (int i = 0; i < testCharacters.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(testCharacters[i] + " occurs " + countOccurencesOf(testCharacters[i], input));
    }
}

public static int countOccurencesOf(char aCharacter, String inThisString)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inThisString.length(); i++)
    {
        if (aCharacter == inThisString.charAt(i)) { count++; }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I put together a char bubble sort for you. There are other ways to do this with less code, using built in sorting methods, but this one shows how an array sort works.

This does not take into account Upper and lower case letters which would change their numeric Unicode value, but this will get you going in the right direction.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[] str = "cabababb".toCharArray(); //Turn your string into an array

    int n = str.length; //get the length of the array
    char temp; //a temporary character holder
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {
            int compare = Character.getNumericValue(str[j - 1]);//get the numeric value of the char
            int compareTo = Character.getNumericValue(str[j]); //etc
            if (compare > compareTo) {//do a compare
                //swap elements  
                temp = str[j - 1]; //bubble sort
                str[j - 1] = str[j];
                str[j] = temp;
            }

        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));//You get your sorted array


}
```

The concept behind a bubble sort does this:

if your array read ['x','j']

these two variables will step into the if statement with comment `//do a compare` if the previous array iteration is greater than the current array iteration:

1. it will put the previous char into a "temp" variable
2. then it will replace the previous char with the current char
3. finally, it will put the current char as the previous char(saved as "temp")

So going back to the example:

> ['x','j']

```
if('x' > 'j'){//for example's sake **Not real code**
//x is in 0 position
//j is in 1 position
                temp = 0 position's value; 
                0 position's value = 1 position's value;
                1 position's value = temp;
}
```

At the end you are left with an alphabetized array.

If you need it back into a string you can concatenate it back into a string

```
String newStr = "";

        for(char letter : str){

           newStr += letter;

        }



        System.out.println(newStr);
```

I hope this helps you understand the concept behind sorting in Java

Answer (score 0):

The requirements need some analysis.

There is a non-functional requirement not to use a hash map. A hash map is just a way to reduce the storage needs for sparse data at the expense of a little time. It's easy to use but makes the code a bit more complicated in Java. So, the straightforward way is to use an array. Memory is cheap, hopefully.

The functional requirements are more problematic:

- *Letters:* Unicode is the character set used by Java and it does have designated letters [Character.isLetter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter-int-)
- *Alphabetical:* Language academies and popular convention determine which letters are in *The Alphabet* and the order of letters the language's various writing systems. As no language or script was mentioned, let's punt on this and use the character set's codepoint ordering (lexicographic) and report on every letter.
- *No need to distinguish between upper and lower case letters:*  Because letter casing is culture/locale-specific, it really would be more straightforward to look at each letter on its own and not try to define sets of upper and lower case letters. (There are more cases anyway.)  It seems stated as an option so let's skip it for now.

.

```
int[] codepointCounts = new int[Character.MAX_CODE_POINT + 1]; // min to max, inclusive

String input = "Häufigkeit der Buchstaben";

for(int c : input.codePoints().toArray()){ 
    codepointCounts[c]++;       
}
for (int c = Character.MIN_CODE_POINT; c <= Character.MAX_CODE_POINT; c++) {
    if (codepointCounts[c] > 0) { 
        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            write(
                new String(Character.toChars(c)) + '\t' + 
                codepointCounts[c] + '\t' + 
                Character.getName(c));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good Points. In reference to Upper and Lower, If "A" and "a" needed to be sorted, The code I provided doe not take care of that. I should have worded it a bit better. Good Points.