# How to count the number of letters that you see in TextView?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-widget

All. I am a new in android developing. Now I am working with TextView. As the case may be I set differnt text. But sometime text is very big. For example, I insert this "abcdefgh_myword", and i get something like that "abcdefg" in my small TextView, but i want to get this "..._myword". So i want to count the number of letters that i see (programly) and set text what i want to see. How to do this? Any ideas?

....

**android:ellipsize="start"**  doesn't work how i want...  Please watch what happen when i  constrict width my TextView

before

[image]

after

[image]

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:ellipsize="start"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="abcdef1234567" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How long is the text expected to be?

Comment: I expected different long text. Long can be very big

Comment: See my edit, maybee this could help http://stackoverflow.com/a/43661224/7325737

Answer (score 1):

This could help you

```
android:ellipsize="start"
android:maxLines="1"
```

add it to the `TextView` in your XML file

**EDIT:**

According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39890995/7325737
you have to use `android:singleLine="true"` because only `end` and `marquee` are supported with `maxLines`

Comment: Thank you,  it works better then    --android:maxLines="1"--

Answer (score 0):

This would be only possible if you knew how wide each symbol is. Which you normally don't, as the font is system dependent.

You could use a monospaced font for this.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for Java's string `length()` method. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252142/how-to-check-how-many-letters-are-in-a-string-in-java) answer. Then either use `android:ellipsize="start"` in XML or `setEllipsize(TruncateAt.START);` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to lidkxx 's answer you would call `getText()` on your text view to get the string.

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);
String s = textview.getText();
int letterCount = s.length();
```