# How can I find out the number of characters in a String in Java?

Tags: java, string, numbers, int, character

This is a simple question but I'm not very good at research.

I'm trying to find out the number of characters in a `String` and put it in an `int` variable. For example:

```
String word = "Hippo";
int numOfCharacters = (the code that tells me how many characters in the word);
```

And then use that number later.

Comment: Do you mean the `length()` of the string or the amount of non-whitespace characters by only counting _word_ characters?

Comment: [How to check how many letters are in a string in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252142/how-to-check-how-many-letters-are-in-a-string-in-java/) This question is already answered, you can check here.

Comment: thanks, as i mentioned i am terrible at searching :)

Comment: @Glains all of the characters including spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [relevant JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) will tell you that  `length()`is the method you're looking for. So `word.length();` would return the size of `word`, which is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use the **.length()** to get the number of characters in a String

```
  String word = "Hippo";
  int numOfCharacters = word.length();
```